# Question on inverse trig functions and quadrants? Please Help!

Tags: functions, trigonometry, circles

Alright, I was doing a question in a book, and it said:

$\displaystyle \cos(2x - \frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

I proceeded and got: $\displaystyle 2x - \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$

I fully simplified but I saw that the answers said there were $4$ possible angles. Why are there $4$?

Comment: Hint: solve for $2x - \pi/6$ using the good old unit circle and the restriction of $x$ to whatever interval it's supposed to be in (you didn't tell us), then solve $2x - \pi/6 = [whatever]$ for $x$.

Comment: In addition to the nice answers, sometimes it helps to plot things to more clearly see what is going on, [*plot using WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos%282x%E2%88%92pi%2F6%29%3Dsqrt%283%29%2F2+x+%3D+0+to+2pi)

Comment: Sorry about that, the interval is 0 ≤ x ≤ 2π

Comment: would x = 30 degrees? If so, would the 4 angles be 30° (Q1), 330° (Q4); then the second rotation would be: 30°+360° = 390°, then 330°+360°=690°? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

However, I still don't fully understand why we do two rotations.

Comment: @missledragon : please heed the answer below that there are actually FIVE solutions if the interval is the CLOSED interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of cosine is $\,\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\,$ at $\,\pm\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi\;,\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ radians , so restricting ourselves to angles in $\,[0,2\pi]\,$ we get

$$\cos\left(2x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\iff 2x-\frac{\pi}{6}=\pm\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi\iff$$

$$x=\begin{cases}\frac{\pi}{6}+k\pi&\implies& \frac{\pi}{6}\;,\;\frac{7\pi}{6}\\{}\\k\pi&\implies&0\;,\;\pi\;,\;\;2\pi\end{cases}$$

Five solutions in the interval $\,[0,2\pi]\;$ , or four in the interval $\,[0,2\pi)\,$

Comment: What do you mean by kπ? Sorry, I'm only in Year 10 :P

Comment: $\,k\,$ is an integer (periodicity of sine and cosine...), and we had to take only those integer multiples that leave us within $\,[0,2\pi]\,$ . For example, $\;k=2\;$ doesn't come into consideration in the first case for $\,x\,$ ,whereas neither negative multiples nor multiples greater than 2 come into consideration in both cases.

Comment: Could you just explain to me why there are two rotations?

Comment: Thanks @amWhy: edited now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still unsure as to why we take into consideration two rotations. If so, can you please explain in a simpler manner ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you call rotations to or, in fact, why you seem to see in $\,0,\pi\,$ rotations but not in the other two: all of them are rotations! Now, you wrote down the equation with $\,\pi\,$ and stuff, which usually means you're not a greenhorne in trigonometry...

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many **real numbers** $x$ such that the equation holds. However, if we restrict $x$ to, say, the interval $[0,2\pi)$, there are only $4$.

Roughly speaking, this is because as $x$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$, the number $2x-\frac{\pi}{6}$ travels through **two complete revolutions** of the unit circle. In any complete revolution of the circle, there are two values of $t$ such that $\cos\left(t-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. This is clear by looking at a picture of the cosine curve.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and DonAntonio's and warned the OP that there are actually five solutions in the closed interval $[0, 2\pi]$, so he may have been given bad instructions.